# Game character is moving too fast

Tags: java

I am currently creating a Java 2D game within which I receive commands from the user to move the character up, down, left or right a certain amount of distance. I am currently using a `for` loop through the user inputs and pass the string to the Player class which will check if the user input string matches one of the direction to move the character. When all of this is executed it appears as though the player has teleported to the end location. Is there a way for the character to move certain amounts of pixels until it has reached the target location to make it seem as though the player is naturally moving to the location.

This is the movePlayer function which is used to loop through the `JTextFields` which contain the user's commands to move the player. The `strings` from each text field is passed into another function: `inputListener`.

```
public void movePlayer(){

    for (int i = 0; i < userTextInput.size(); i++) {
        inputListener(userTextInput.get(i).getText());
    }
}
```

The `inputListener` checks if the `strings` entered by the user matches the movement type, and the initiates the appropriate method to move the character.

```
private void inputListener(String Input){

     if(Input.equals("up")){
         player.moveCharacterUp();

     }else if(Input.equals("down")){
         player.moveCharacterDown();

     }else if(Input.equals("left")){
         player.moveCharacterLeft();

     }else if(Input.equals("right")){
         player.moveCharacterRight();

     }

}
```

This is where the `x` and `y` position of the character is set according to the method run from `inputListener`

```
public void moveCharacterUp(){
    y -= moveSpeed;
} 

public void moveCharacterDown(){
    y += moveSpeed;
}

public void moveCharacterLeft(){
    x -= moveSpeed;
}

public void moveCharacterRight(){
    x += moveSpeed;
}
```

The run method for the `Thread` which I am using.

```
public void run(){

    init();

    long start;
    long elapsed;
    long wait;

    while(running){

        start = System.nanoTime();

        update();
        draw();
        drawToScreen();

        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;

        if(wait < 0) wait = 5;

        try{
            Thread.sleep(wait);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
    }
```

Comment: An (over)simplistic approach might be to use `Thread.sleep(200);` or something similar in your game loop.

Comment: That won't change the distance or the speed of the character moving, it will only create a slight pause in the thread, which I can only imagine would be very irritating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have done this in the past is by creating a `targetX` and `targetY`.
I then increment `x` and `y` until they equal `targetX` and `targetY`.

```
int x = 0; //Character's x position
int y = 0; //Character's y position
int targetX = 0; //Character's target x position
int targetY = 0; //Character's target y position
int moveSpeed = 2; //the speed at which the character moves
int moveAmt = 20; //amount the character is set to move every time it is told to move

void setTarget(int targetX, int targetY) //sets targetX and targetY, doesn't need to be called at all
{
    this.targetX = targetX;
    this.targetY = targetY;
}

void moveCharacter(int x, int y) //moves the character, doesn't need to be called at all
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

void updatePosition() //initiates/continues movement, should be called every frame
{
    if(Input.equals("up")) {
         setTarget(targetX, targetY - moveAmt);

    } else if(Input.equals("down")) {
         setTarget(targetX, targetX + moveAmt);

    } else if(Input.equals("left")) {
         setTarget(targetX - moveAmt, targetX);

    } else if(Input.equals("right")) {
         setTarget(targetX + moveAmt, targetX);

    }

    if(y > targetY) {
         player.moveCharacter(x, y - moveSpeed);

    } else if(y < targetY) {
         player.moveCharacter(x, y + moveSpeed);

    } else if(x > targetX) {
         player.moveCharacter(x - moveSpeed, y);

    } else if(x < targetX) {
         player.moveCharacter(x + moveSpeed, y);

    }
}
```

Comment: should I be setting using the setTarget() like this: setTarget(x +=moveSpeed, y += moveSpeed) ?

Comment: `setTarget()` sets the place that the player will move to, `updatePosition()` should be called every frame to make the player move towards the target, and `moveCharacter()` does not need to be called at all. Also, `moveSpeed` probably needs to be adjusted to suit your needs.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem a little bit. I am not moving the character based on key press events. I am moving the character a certain amount of pixels for example 20 pixels for every command which `updatePosition` recieves, which might be `up`, `down`, `left` or `right`. Even when I implemented your code the character did move, but it moved instantly not for example 2 pixels at a time to make it appear as it is moving.

Comment: @Human I just modified the code a bit. Also, `Input` should be set to some arbitrary String, e.g. `"0"` at the beginning of every frame. Failure to do so may result in your character constantly moving in one direction.

Comment: @Human Oops, didn't see your last comment. The modified code should work. `moveSpeed` is the speed at which it moves, `moveAmt` is the amount that the target moves by when `Input` is set to `"up"`, `"down"`, etc..

Comment: @Human Oh, wait! I just had a thought. Are you using a frame based realtime loop, where everything is processed once every (for example) 1/60th of a second, or are you using a loop that pauses until a command is entered? (sorry for the incessant comments)

Comment: I have an infinite while loop so I guess it would be realtime loop. I could put the code up for the Thread loop if you want.

Comment: @Human OK, my code should work with a few modifications to fit your code, provided that you set `Input` to an arbitrary string before—or at the beginning of—the `update()` method that is called in the `main` method.

Comment: Hi RyanCarlson. Sorry or the late reply, my internet died for two days. Your code was very helpful so thanks for your help. However, I am receiving multiple commands from the user up to four times. So the user could request `up` four times or which ever combination of direction they choose. To move the character in each of the direction that the user has specified I tried creating a 2D array to store the `setTarget`s and access them within `updatePosition()` in a `for` loop. However that made the character move really fast again. Is there anything that comes to your mind for this?

Comment: Imagine that you tell the character `up` and `left`. Do you want the character to move **a)** diagonally up and across, or **b)** up, _then_ across? If you want option a, you can replace the `x`s and `y`s in the first half of `updatePosition()` with `targetX`s and `targetY`s, respectively. I modified the code above to look like that. If you want option b, I would suggest doing what you have been with the arrays. About it moving too fast, I would suggest changing `moveSpeed`. With the above code your character will move the 20 pixels in 10 frames, which is pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

The speed is set by the variable moveSpeed. This is probably set to a higher value than what you want, so try changing that.

Comment: if I change the moveSpeed to 20 for example to move 20 pixels up, the character will do that, but it will do it in an instant and not slowly as if a person is holding down a key.

Answer (score 0):

Your program need to count time. That time value will be use to scale moveSpeed. Key is pressed and you fetch current time. When you are about to apply moveSpeed you have to fetch time once again and calculate difference with previous time. That difference will be your scale factor. Something like this:

```
private void inputListener(String Input){
   lastTime = getTime();
}

public void moveCharacterUp(){
   currTime = getTime();
   y -= moveSpeed * (currTime - lastTime)
   lastTime = currTime;
}
```